# what is the difference between java.nio.file.Path and java.nio.*;

Tags: java

when i looked at the source code of Scanner in java i found something confused me

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.*;
```

what is the difference between them, why they didn't just imported java.nio.*?
thank you.

Comment: `import java.nio.file.Path;` to keep things straightward

Comment: importing wildcard seems to be practical, until you don't use multiple frameworks and libraries where you may have conflicking names

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wildcards are not recursive.  `import java.nio.*` imports everything directly under `java.nio`, but not any deeper than that.

In fact, "deeper" is a misleading term in itself.  Packages in Java don't form a hierarchy - they aren't really nested in any semantic way.  `java.nio.file` and `java.nio` are no more related to each other than `foo` and `bar` are to each other.

Comment: Exactly right.  There's no concept of tree structure in imports, even though we know it maps onto a directory tree.  No recursion.

Answer (score 1):

`java.nio.*` only imports the classes in that `package` but not in its `subpackages`.